# Interacting with Qt widgets on different levels

Tags: qt

I'm creating a GUI with Qt and I'm trying to interact with elements on different levels.

```
#include <QtGui>
#include "mywindow.h"
#include "component.h"
#include "przystanki.h"
MyWindow::MyWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent)
{
    webView = new MyWebView(this);
    mainlayout = new QGridLayout();
    mainlayout->addWidget(webView, 0,0);
    Przystanki *stop = new Przystanki(this);
    mainlayout->addWidget(stop, 0, 1);
    QHBoxLayout* bottom = new QHBoxLayout();
    bottom->addWidget(new Component("Linie"));
    bottom->addWidget(new Component("Autobusy"));
    QHBoxLayout* hrightCorner = new QHBoxLayout();
    QVBoxLayout* rightCorner = new QVBoxLayout();
    rightCorner->addStretch(1);
    rightCorner->addWidget(new QPushButton("Start", this));
    rightCorner->addStretch(1);
    hrightCorner->addLayout(rightCorner);
    mainlayout->addLayout(bottom, 1, 0);
    mainlayout->addLayout(hrightCorner, 1, 1);
    hrightCorner->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    this->setCentralWidget(new QWidget);
    this->centralWidget()->setLayout(mainlayout);

}
```

In the webView I've got a method inside which I want to add an element to a list which is in the Przystanki class.

How can I do it? Is it possible to access it in an easy way or do I have to refactor my code in some way? (If so please give me some advice in what way I should do it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could:

- add a signal in the `MyWebView` class with the data you wish to add as a parameter,
- add a slot in the `Przystanki` class with the same parameter type as the signal,
- connect the signal to the slot in `QMainWindow` constructor.

This way, the `MyWebView` class doesn't need to know anything about the `Przystanki` class, and it just has to emit a signal.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a system of [setter/getter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method).

What I would do is, in your class `Webview`, create an object `Przystanki * przystanik` in private.
Webview.h:

```
#include "przystanki.h"

class Webview{
    Webview(Przstanki *);
    Przstanki * przystanik;
}
```

In your class `Przystanki` create a function getter: `type_of_list Przystanki::get_list()`.
Przstanki.cpp:

```
list_type Przstanki::get_list(){
    return list;
}
```

So now, inside `Wedview`, your object przystanik can call get_list: `przystanik->get_list()`.

webview.cpp:

```
Webview::Webview(Przstanki * stop){
    przystanik = stop;
}

Webview::your_method(){
    Przystanik->get_list();
}
```